# Using an array to store and call cell values

Tags: vba, excel, numbers

I'm trying to make an array that will store lots of inputs based of a variable amount of input. Trying to use an array my code is:

```
Dim cellValue, x, dupval As Long
dupval = dupbox.Value
Dim anArray()
With ActiveSheet
    .Cells(14, 4) = dupval
End With
x = 0
For i = 1 To dupval
    MsgBox (i)
    cellValue = InputBox("What is the first row of the duplicate?")
    anArray(i) = Cells(cellValue, 3)
Next i
For i = anArray(1) To anArray(dupval)
    x = x + anArray(i).Value
Next i
```

In my first for loop `anArray(i)`returns `Subsript out of range`. The cell value is 0 in my sheet. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not use an array??? Or a dictionary?

Comment: My coding is very limited, so I have no idea what an array is. Thanks for the tip though!

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim anArray(), _
    aValue As Long
aValue = 100 'or anything else
ReDim anArray(aValue)

For i = 1 To aValue
    anArray(i) = cellValue
    'Or
    anArray(i) = cells(i,1)
Next i

anArray = Range("C12:E22").Value
```

With the last part, `anArray(1,1)` will be C12 value.

You can get array start and stop values with `LBound(anArray, Dimension)` or `UBound(anArray, Dimension)`

So you can loop on array with `For i = LBound(anArray, 1) or UBound(anArray, 1)`

Comment: I think I understand what's going on with this. If I wanted to call the values from the array to do math with how would I about it? I am trying to use the stored values to find an average, so '(anArray(1)+anArray(2)..+anArray(i))/i'

Comment: Indeed you can! And for the good news, arrays are incredibly faster than working with cells! Take a look at the edit to see how to fill an array from a range! ;)

Comment: Now to just figure out what I am actually looking for. I keep finding out more and more stuff I need haha. This is dumb.

Comment: On using that my first value returns `<Subscript out of range>`.

Comment: @R3uK - your example code creates a zero-based array: might be better to explicitly state a lower bound of one.